# Mark sender as non-junk email sender in Outlook 2013

Tags: spam-prevention, microsoft-outlook-2013

For some reason Outlook 2013 is hellbent on putting all email sent from some email addresses into the *Junk Email* folder, despite these emails being legitimate and safe. Moving all of these emails to the Inbox doesn't help — Outlook insists incoming email from these addresses are junk.

Obviously I need to classify these senders as *Safe Senders* so that their emails arrive in my Inbox, but cannot figure out a way to do so.

Comment: Do you have any anti-spam add-ons in Outlook?  Because you should be able to just right click on the email and/or use the Junk button to resolve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have no such options (and no special anti-spam add-on). In previous Outlook versions I remember this was straightforward (just right-click).

Comment: When I right click on an email I have a Junk-> option.  If you don't have this then its disabled in your configuration.

Comment: https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/overview-of-the-junk-email-filter-HA102748954.aspx